# Unexpected JAR was built into my project library by maven

Tags: maven, build

There are 2 issues when i built my projects via maven.

1. The dependency "stax-stax-api-1.0.jar" was always built into my library folder, however, i didn't declare it in any of my project POM.
2. So i start to think if it's a dependency of other JARs i am using, but i analysis all my libraries, i can't find any relationship between "stax-stax-api-1.0.jar" with other JARs. (i used "jarAnalyzer" to analysis my libraries)
3. Finally, i found that i can't find the JAR in internet by name "stax-stax-api-1.0.jar", i can only found "stax-api-1.0.jar", that's why i failed to exclude it in maven by "exclusion" and "optional" tag.

So any idea about this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [maven dependency plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/), and its [dependency:tree](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/tree-mojo.html) goal to have maven display your project's dependency tree.

Simply execute `mvn dependency:tree` from the command line.

From the output that this produces you will then be able to see exactly where the `stax-stax-api` dependency is coming from.

Comment: This is a cool tool and more convenient than jarAnalyzer, although i fixed the issue, but i still have some confusion about the dependency management. <br/></br> Below are the analysis result: [INFO] |  +- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile <br/> [INFO] +- javax.xml.stream:stax-api:jar:1.0:compile </br>Neither of them will produce a jar with signature "stax-stax-api-1.0.jar".